# convert square regression model to linear model

Tags: statistics, regression

The question is:

"Show how the nonlinear regression equation $y=a(x-b)+c(x-b)^2$ can be converted to a linear regression equation solvable by the method of least squares."

if we take that
\begin{align}
a(x-b) - c(x-b)^2 &= ax - ab + cx^2 -2cbx - cb^2\\
                  & = \underbrace{-ab-cb^2}_{\beta_0} + x\underbrace{(a-2cb)}_{\beta_1} + x^2\underbrace{c}_{\beta_2}\\
\end{align}
thus,
$$
 y_i = \beta_0+\beta_1 x_i + \beta_2 x_i^2 + \epsilon_i, \quad i=1,...,n.
$$

$ 
\beta_0$ and $\beta_1 $ are dependent each other ,so if you take the partial derivative of $y_i$ for $\beta_0$ you got dependence on $\beta_1$ ,so the gradient of Y by given X dependent on unknown parameters and we got non linear model.

or if you take the next model

\begin{align}
xb + (xb)^2 +(xb)^3 &= \underbrace{xb}_{\beta_0} + x^2\underbrace{(b^2)}_{\beta_1} + x^3\underbrace{b^3}_{\beta_2}\\
\end{align}
thus,
$$
 y_i = \beta_0x+\beta_1 x_i^2 + \beta_2 x_i^3 + \epsilon_i, \quad i=1,...,n.
$$

and you got a linear model but of course is not a linear model because $\beta_0$ and $\beta_1$ are dependent.

Any help explaining this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
\begin{align}
a(x-b) - c(x-b)^2 &= ax - ab + cx^2 -2cbx - cb^2\\
                  & = \underbrace{-ab-cb^2}_{\beta_0} + x\underbrace{(a-2cb)}_{\beta_1} + x^2\underbrace{c}_{\beta_2}\\
\end{align}
thus,
$$
 y_i = \beta_0+\beta_1 x_i + \beta_2 x_i^2 + \epsilon_i, \quad i=1,...,n.
$$

Comment: but betha_0 and betha_1 are dependent each other and in linear model the parameters are independent each other?

Comment: Nope, in general $cov(\hat{\beta}_0, \hat{\beta}_1) \neq 0$.

Comment: so what defines a linear regression?

Comment: Whether the partial derivatives w.r.t. $\beta_j$ is independent of the other unknown $\beta$s.

Comment: two questions:1)if we take y =β0+ β1^2*x is non linear model because the β1^2 but if we take the partial derivative for β1 we got 2*β1*x its not dependent on β0 and you wrote "independent of the other unknown βs"(mark on "other" I think you mean other betha not include betha1)   another question if we take this model y=β0+β1x+β2x^2

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: sorry I didn't finish the question.                                                                         1)if we take y =β0+ β1^2*x is non linear model because the β1^2 but if we take the partial derivative for β1 we got 2*β1*x its not dependent on β0 and you wrote "independent of the other unknown βs"(mark on "other" I think you mean other betha not include betha1)   another question if we take this model y=β0+β1x+β2x^2 and take the derivative for betha0 we got y'=1? if yes ,so why, betha1 dependent on betha0 and therefore betha1 not disapear from the partial derivative? thanks a lot.

Comment: 1. You are right, the more formal definition is that the gradient of the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X$ should not include any unknown parameters. 2. I'm note sure what you are asking. Anyway, if it not explicitly related to the original question, maybe you should ask a new question as the comments are mainly  for comments of the current question and are not so suitable for long discussions

Comment: okay I edited the question.